# Laravel JSON validation failed with postman

Tags: php, json, laravel, editorjs

I am sending a post request using postman to my Laravel API.

```
{
    "title" : "abc",
    "body" : [
        {"type":"paragraph","data":{"text":"aSADAd"}},
        {"type":"header","data":{"text":"Heading......","level":2}},
        {"type":"paragraph","data":{"text":"This is a para"}},
        {"type":"list","data":{"style":"ordered","items":["ABC","XYZ"]}}
    ],
    "status" : 1
}
```

The body field is a JSON data field - the JSON.stringify output from the editor js.

My laravel validation rules are -

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'body' => 'required|json',
            'status' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
```

But I m getting this error -

```
{
    "validation_error": {
        "body": [
            "The body must be a valid JSON string."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `body` is not a JSON string, that's correct. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: If this wasn't just that you expected the wrong thing, this should be a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `array`

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'body' => 'required|array',
    'status' => 'required|boolean'
]);
```

this will work if you set your model

```php
/**
 * The attributes that has json type.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'body' => 'array'
];
```

like this you can work with json mysql in laravel

> **NOTE** :  The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

### Ref links

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

https://laraveldaily.com/working-with-mysql-json-columns-in-laravel-custom-properties-example/

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/saving-an-array-into-a-json-column-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: Yes, it will pass the validation. But in my database, I m using  - $table->json('body');

Comment: What is "original json"?